# Would this be a valid C I/O library?

Tags: c++, c

I have a question.  I want to create a simple C I/O library, and I wish to check whether the method I am using is the correct one.  The code is effectively pseudocode, so ignore the syntax.

```
Simple I/O Library:
Output is 0x0000
Input is 0xFFFF

void writeChar (char* po) {
   char* ph = 0x0000
   char po;
   *ph = po
}

char readChar () {
   char* pi = 0xFFFF
   char in
   in = *pi
   return in
}
```

**Update:**Sorry if I wasn't clear.  This is for an memory-mapped I/O system.  The values are simply examples.  I just wanted to test if the idea is valid.

**One More Question:** I would like to understand the difference between memory access and port access.  What, if any, changes would be required to access a port instead of a memory location, assuming a port-mapped I/O system this time.

Comment: It sounds like a great library for creating access violations :)

Comment: Not valid, here `*ph = po` you are dereferencing a pointer to `NULL` (0x0000 = NULL)

Comment: @KeineLust I understand that.  As I said, the values were simply an example.

Comment: @FoggyDay Which parts of it would do that?

Comment: If it's valid, written in C or callable from C, and doing I/O, it;'s a valid C I/O library. There is no port access in C. If ports on your machine are not memory mapped, you will probably need to use assembly.

Comment: It would be a valid C I/O library if (a) it compiled, which it doesn't, and (b) if the memory addresses concerned were correct, about which you have provided zero information. As things are, it isn't.

Comment: @EJP As I stated in my question, the values are examples and would be changed to fit the hardware.  Also, I said it was pseudocode to test the idea, so I would obviously need to be changed to fit correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system memory maps port I/O registers, then something along the lines of your pseudo code would work fine.

Real C code would look something like this:

```
void writeChar (uint8_t po) {
   volatile uint8_t* ph = (volatile uint8_t*)0x0000;
   *ph = po
}

uint8_t readChar (void) {
   volatile uint8_t* pi = (volatile uint8_t*)0xFFFF
   return *pi;
}
```

Real code would never use the `char` type since it has implementation-defined signedness. That is, `char` is useless for hardware-related programming since it is unreliable. You could however use `unsigned char`.

Also, real code must include the cast, since you cannot assign an integer to a pointer in standard C.

> I would like to understand the difference between memory access and port access. What, if any, changes would be required to access a port instead of a memory location, assuming a port-mapped I/O system this time.

There's no real difference, in case of memory-mapped registers. This is all determined by the hardware. You'd have to read the manual about the specific register to see how it should be used.